# What does SHA256 change for us?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, certification

One of our clients got a mail saying the webservice will change to SHA256.

"On October 11‚ 2016‚ the SHA‑1 certificate for webservice.exacttarget.com will be replaced with a SHA‑256 certificate. To avoid any disruptions of service‚ customers must verify that their systems are ready for this change before October 11."

Is this only for the SOAP api? 
And if it is, does this mean that all our webservices that use SOAP needs to be configured differently somehow?

Answer (score 5):

The underlying certificate provided by Salesforce for the connection is changing. This means that you will have to check that the integration you are using can use a SHA-256 certificate.

Salesforce has provided a test endpoint for you to test - [TEST SHA2 endpoint](https://webservice-sha2.exacttarget.com)

Also you can register for more information at the [Salesforce group Marketing Cloud Certificate Change](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009Qpn) and follow the discussion on this there